# Was there ever a tautology that was first discovered as a physical law?

Tags: history

Has there ever been a discovery of a law that was first identified as a physical law (law of nature), and was later found out to be a mathematical result (tautology) of physical laws that were already known at the time?

I am thinking of something like the uncertainty principle which was first recognised as a result in quantum mechanics, but can be derived from Fourier analysis with no reference to physical facts at all, other than definitions (physical constants are of course derived experimentally). That would be an example for me, except that I am neither sure that the uncertainty principle has first been discovered in physics nor whether its status as a mathematical fact is accepted. Is there a less controversial case?

Comment: I am not seeing as your example point to a new mathematical fact. That something must descend from mathematics is not new mathematics.  But perhaps the Q is unclear to me

Comment: @alchimistra: It is not a new mathematical fact, true. The question is about a “new” physical fact that turned out not to be physical but just an application of known mathematical theory.

Comment: How about various conservation laws being mathematically equivalent to symmetries via Noether's theorem?

Comment: Once you've decided on a particular model then all of its consequences are mathematical. But I suppose that it may not be immediately obvious how some physical phenomenon covered by the model follows mathematically from the core formulation of the model.

Comment: How about Kepler's laws of planetary motion?

Comment: @Lewis Miller: Kepler’s laws can certainly be deduced from Newton laws, but these were discovered much later. So we can think of Newton laws as extensions to Kepler’s.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be moved to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I see. But it is unclear now how the two uncertainties are the same. What would happen if we FT macroscopic wave such in a big pool? Sorry to detour from the original Q but I got intrigued

Comment: @FGSUZ: it does belong to hsm.stackexchange.com, which I didn't know about. Mea culpa.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's inevitable that any answer to this question is largely subjective (what do we take as axioms in the laws of physics?), but Maxwell's correction to Ampère's law fits the bill pretty squarely. Here's the law in vacuum, with the boxed term being the correction:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \mathbf{J} + \boxed{\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}}$$

In short, the boxed term was [initially introduced](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/On_Physical_Lines_of_Force.pdf) by Maxwell as a way to describe polarization currents in dielectrics, but it turns out that such a term is *mathematically required* as a result of conservation of electric charge.

Comment: unless by the variable $\epsilon_0$ you also mean the permittivity of ponderable matter *your* equation is not what Maxwell had in mind when described polarization currents in dielectrics.

Comment: Maxwell most certainly did not have this vacuum form of the equation in mind when he came up with it originally, but the key is that general displacement current term he did come up with possesses the same linear dependence on the rate of change of the electric field, and it is this dependence that is required to satisfy conservation of electric charge.

Comment: This is probably a perfect answer if the conservation of electric charge was known before Maxwell’s paper. I looked that up and it seems that the conservation of charge was proven by Faraday a couple of decades before Maxwell’s answer. Can anybody confirm or refute that?

Comment: "mathematically required" Mathematics only requires consistency. It was physically required.

Comment: My understanding of "mathematically required" here is logically required, or required as a consistent corollary of, the conservation of electric charge.

Answer (score 0):

> something like the uncertainty principle which was first recognised as a result in quantum mechanics, but can be derived from Fourier analysis with no reference to physical facts at all, other than definitions

This is plain wrong, particularly in your claim that there is "no reference to physical facts at all". The uncertainty principle can indeed be derived within Fourier analysis as regards the uncertainties in the position and the wavevector of a given wavepacket, but to get to the Heisenberg version you need to switch to the momentum instead of the wavevector, and that can only be done via de Broglie's relation (i.e. a physical fact).

The example you're pointing to is not a tautology - it is a mathematical relationship between different sets of laws of nature. Finding those relationships is the bread and butter of physics.

As such, your question seems to be left without any meaningful examples of what you mean by "tautology".

Comment: Getting to the _Heisenberg_ uncertainty inequality definitely requires a physical fact, yes. Getting to the fact that non-commuting pairs of variables will be limited in accuracy if measured doesn't need that. That is what I meant by the [uncertainty principle](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/06/25/the-uncertainty-principle/).

Comment: Either way, it is in no sense a tautology.

Comment: One can understand a tautology to be a true fact that is not contingent. The claim here is that the mathematical uncertainty principle is not contingent on the universe or parts thereof.

Comment: That much was clear about your claim from the start. Your claim is wrong. If you want to discuss your personal theories about the world without bothering to check how the world behaves, this site is not the appropriate venue.

Comment: Except that I was talking about mathematics. Not about the physics of the world, or my alternative theories of the world (which don’t exist).

Comment: The original question again: has there ever been a discovery of a physical law that is a mathematical corollary of existing known physical laws at the time, but the fact that it is a corollary was discovered much later?